# What is serving static files?

Tags: node.js

I Googled this and all that came up was how to serve static files.

I couldn't find what serving meant or what static files were.

Could someone write a detailed explanation of this.  I'm a bit new so try not to use very technical terms.

I don't really know what to tag this with so feel free to edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are building a web application you have generally two kinds of things that the server sends to the client (browser).

Static Files - These are files that don't change.  Think of things like style sheets, javascript, and images.  They aren't dependant on any user input generally.

Dynamic Stuff - A webserver may need to query a database and return variable things like records of usuarios, information, etc that is dependant on some type of user input.  These are considered dynamic because they can change based on whatever the application is doing.

In I think express or maybe some other frameworks you can specify a route for the static files so the server knows to just send them to the browser/client as opposed to having to process some route information, make a query, etc.

`Serve` just means to send to the client.